# WCF hosting mutiple endpoints with TCP

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets, tcp

I'm having issue's hosting multiple endpoints on WCF, it's giving me error:

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a
>   listener on IP endpoint 
>   0.0.0.0:808. This could happen if there is another application already listening on this endpoint or if you have multiple service endpoints
>   in your service host with the same IP endpoint but with incompatible
>   binding configurations. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only
>   one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted at system.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

**My App.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
            <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
      </system.web>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
          <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
        </diagnostics>

        <bindings>
          <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="TCPDefault" portSharingEnabled="true" />
          </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
         <!--Service1-->
          <service name="WCFLibrary.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="DebugBehavior">
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/CalculatorService" />

              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPDefault"
              name="ServiceTCPEndPoint" contract="WCFLibrary.ICalculator">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
           <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceMexEndPoint"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         </service>
         <!--Service2-->
          <service name="WCFLibrary.MyWorldService" behaviorConfiguration="DebugBehavior">
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/MyWorldService" />

              </baseAddresses>          
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPDefault"
          name="WCFLibrary.MyWorldService" contract="WCFLibrary.IMyWorld">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceMexEndPoint"
               contract="IMetadataExchange" />          
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DebugBehavior">

              <serviceMetadata/>

              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>

I'm having separate services with callbacks. Please advise.

**Modified App.config**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="TCPDefault" portSharingEnabled="true" />
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
     <!--Service1-->
      <service name="WCFLibrary.CalculatorService" behaviorConfiguration="DebugBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/CalculatorService" />

          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPDefault"
          name="ServiceTCPEndPoint" contract="WCFLibrary.ICalculator">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
       <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8002/CalculatorService/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceMexEndPoint"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
     <!--Service2-->
      <service name="WCFLibrary.MyWorldService" behaviorConfiguration="DebugBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!--<add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/MyWorldService" />-->

          </baseAddresses>          
        </host>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/MyWorldService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TCPDefault"
      name="WCFLibrary.MyWorldService" contract="WCFLibrary.IMyWorld">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8001/MyWorldService/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceMexEndPoint"
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />          
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DebugBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="False" />-->
          <serviceMetadata/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**WCF:**

> http://pastebin.com/gHHRKeYZ

**WindowsService:**

> http://pastebin.com/kjM3iRYj

Answer (score 2):

It appears the problem is with your MEX endpoints - they are identical between the two services. Try giving them different addresses to see if this resolves the problem.

Comment: With this I can get the WCF running with the test client. But when I host this in windows service, I can't download the metadata using svcutil

Comment: Can you post exactly how your modified your .config file and what error message you get when try to use svcutil against the service?

Comment: Please check my edit. When I'm running the service through service manager, i use svcutil to test the service, which also downloads the metadata. It says : Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost/CalculatorService. The same goes for the second endpoint

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you have another application that listen on the some  port try  to change the port to something like this 
try a different port on both

```
  <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:2200/CalculatorService" />
 <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost/MyWorldService:2200" />
```

if this succeed  try to list all apps and listening port using this command

```
netstat -an
```

Comment: AFischbein's solution has some what worked but as this is hosted in windows service, I'm not able to download the metadate from svcutil

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have update the .net framework and i receive this error. I resolve this error by removing the listenBacklog and  maxConnections attributes of  in configuration file

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2012/10/16/nettcpbinding-amp-mextcpbinding-sharing-same-port-throws-addressalreadyinuseexception-on-upgrade-to-net-4-5.aspx) is the solution which resolve my problem.